# How to pass int value from web input to domain int in c# asp.net-mvc 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, object

I am a new developer and I am running into a problem where I want to assign an existing integer (on the domain) a value that is coming in from a user input from the web.  How do I do this?  Below is the code from my App solution.

Current error message: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'AppDomain.MainFrame.Entities'

**model snippet: (WebFrame.cs)**

```
namespace AppWeb.Models
```

{
    public class WebFrame
    {
    ...
    public int Urgency {get; set;}
    ...
   }
}

**contoller snippet: (WebFrameController.cs)** - WHERE I NEED HELP.  I tried a few different thing but all resulted in the same error.

```
namespace AppWeb.Controllers
    {
        public class WebFrameController : Controller
        {
            ...
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase FileIn, WebFrame webFrameWork)
            {
            ...
                if (webFrame.Urgency != 0)
                    {   
                     //>>> *** THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP, I'VE TRIED A FEW THINGS TO NO AVAIL, INCLUDING HARDCODING NEEDDONEINDAYS =1*** <<<  
                    //TODO:Assign Urgency from MVC Web App user input to Need Done In           Days Value (= NeedDoneInDays) in Domain 
                     Entities NeedDoneInDays = new Entities(); 
                     NeedDoneInDays = webFrame.Urgency; 
                     //NeedDoneInDays = 1; 
                     //NeedDoneInDays = Urgency;                
                    }
                  .... does some processing to get to Log if necessary.
             } 
            ...
        }
    }
```

Page that has functions that will accept the Urgency Value.

**AppDomain.MainFrame.Entities.Reporting.cs**.

```
namespace AppDomain.MainFrame.Entities 
    { 
     public class Reporting 
         { 

          public static void LogToMainLogAndProcess(System.Web.HttpRequest hReq,           System.DateTime StartTime, string projectType, int NeedDoneInDays) 
            { 
             //does some processing... logging and storing... 
            }
          public static void LogAndReport(System.Web.HttpRequest hReq, string          Department, System.DateTime StartTime, string projectType, int NeedDoneInDays)
          {
               //does some processing... logging and storing... 
          }    
       } 
   }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign an integer value webFrame.urgency to an object of type Entities, this doesn't make sense, hence the error.  Is it that the Entities object has a property for urgency which is an integer ?

Comment: No, Urgency is an int that I want to represent int NeedDoneInDays.  How can this not be done? I may be taking the wrong approach, because pass by type/object is a little confusing.  But my goal is to get the value that's been assigned to int Urgency to be set to int NeedDoneInDays.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Issue has been resolved.  The function was being called in another page, and I was able to pass the value successfully to that page.  Thanks for the help!